# Concatenating strings into one

Tags: python, string, list, text

I have a dataframe with different comments that were made and their characteristics. 
I have a column which is called "Free Text"

Basically, it contains for each comment the text corresponding to it.

Each of the rows contains a string, how can I paste all those strings together to get one single string?

I tried

```
data['text'].str.cat(sep=', ')
```

But I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: This error tells you, that data is a list. You only can access list items by their index like data[0], data[1].... Add some more of your code please. is data a list of dictionaries for the comments?

Comment: instead of doing .str try doing .__str__ or str(data['text']) and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas concatenate a Series of strings into one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400381/python-pandas-concatenate-a-series-of-strings-into-one-string)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like, it would work only in case `data['text'].values` results in **string**. if not you will have to convert that to string.

```
",".join(data['text'].values)
```

and here is a proper example

```
df = DataFrame(randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'), dtype=str)

print df['A'].values # prints all the values as list 
print ",".join(df['A'].values) # prints all the values as string seperated by ,
```