# Converting a pandas series to a string array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
ind  
0   ['C']
1   ['C']
2   ['C']
3   ['C']
4   ['E']
5   ['E']
```

I want to convert it into a string: `CCCCEE`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400381/python-pandas-concatenate-a-series-of-strings-into-one-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas concatenate a Series of strings into one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400381/python-pandas-concatenate-a-series-of-strings-into-one-string)

Answer (score 4):

You can using `str`

```
df['ind'].str[0].sum()
Out[197]: 'CCCCEE'
```

Comment: ind is not an actual column name, just the default python dataframe indexing. Could you please suggest how should I proceed?

Comment: @KrishnaAnapindi You mean: `df.index.str[0].sum()`?

Comment: gives an error saying 'Index' object has no attribute to sum

Comment: @KrishnaAnapindi it is not like a index in your sample data

Comment: Yeah just replace 'ind' with the name of the column containing the strings

Comment: @KrishnaAnapindi seems like it is Series not data frame , `df.str[0].sum()`

Comment: @Wen If it is a series however OP should avoid to use the variable name `df` and change it to `s` which is the common variable name for series. Good guess though, probably it.

Comment: @AntonvBR my guess that ind is index name ：-）

Answer (score 3):

Using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'ind': [['C'], ['C'], ['C'], ['C'], ['E'], ['E']]})

res = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(df['ind']))

print(res)

CCCCEE
```

Comment: Sure but shouldn't `''.join(chain.from_iterable(df['ind']))` suffice?

Comment: @AntonvBR, The `list` conversion is intentional, [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238/9209546). You're right that accessing `values` is unnecessary, updated.

Comment: Oh.. it is that same old thing. Yeah that is probably right but I feel it looses readability when applying multiple layers of parenthesis.

Comment: Ok I ran some timings with a very large dataframe and I interpret it like this: the `str.join` will convert a generator to a list before applying the `join` and it is therefore recommended to do `[]` a list comprehension over a `()` expression. However when the returning value as in this case is an iterator there is no point to convert it to a list as this will be done by the `str.join` anyway. I therefore think you are wrong in this particular case and that the `list()` only creates the extra layer of parenthesis.

Comment: @AntonvBR, That's interesting, and I agree `list` is expensive. Looks like I need to dig a little deeper. Thanks :).

Comment: In any case. Nice solution. Sorry for spamming comments.

Comment: @AntonvBR, No.. in fact, I think this is precisely the purpose of comments. Learn something new!

Comment: OK last thing. Let's leave this question open for the future. The answer might not be right but I strongly believe it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
chain=""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    chain=chain+row['column']
return chain
```

If you have a problem iterating over a dataframe, you can check this [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)